# Why is there no available byte order conversion method for floating-point numbers? Also, why do floating-point numbers work without conversion?

Tags: c++, networking, byte

I am working on parsing packets received in binary format. I have to do byte order conversion for integrals, but it is a bit strange for me as it seems floating-point numbers work fine without conversion. Are floating-point numbers are always in little-endian byte order? Why don't we have ntof or ntod function in arpa/inet or other Unix network libraries?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is there no available byte order conversion method for floating-point numbers?

The representation with flipped byte order can't be placed into a floating-point variable at all, due to signalling NaNs.

To do byte order conversion for floating-point values, read from the input into an integer-typed or untyped (e.g. array of `std::byte`) buffer, use a byte swap operation that works on such a buffer, and reinterpret as a floating-point value only after the byte order is corrected.

For output, reinterpret into a buffer first, and then do the byte order swap on the buffer (which has no floating-point type).

> Are floating-point numbers are always in little-endian byte order?

No.

> Why don't we have `ntohf` or `ntohd` function in arpa/inet or other Unix network libraries?

None of the packets in any standard protocol contain floating-point numbers.  The network library isn't providing `ntohs` and `ntohl` for convenient manipulation of application data, but for manipulation of header fields such as IP address and TCP port number.

If you do define convenience functions for yourself, be sure to use a non-floating-point type for the network side.  That is, you should write

```
uint32_t htonf(float);
float ntohf(uint32_t);
uint64_t htond(double);
double ntohd(uint64_t);
```

or probably even better, break with the scalar-in-scalar-out convention and use `std::span<std::byte, width>` for the network-side.  This will resolve the alignment issues that would otherwise arise with stuffing the IEEE double-precision bit representation into a `uint64_t`, since the standard network protocols only provide 32-bit alignment.

Comment: 80-bit `long double` is even a bit more fun, because on some platforms it will have 2 padding bytes (size is 12), and other platforms it will have 6 padding bytes (size is 16).  And there are platforms where `long double` is just the same as `double`.  Regardless of the `long double`, if one platform is IEEE 754, and the other platform has some other floating point representation... then there's more than byte order to worry about.

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, incompatible representations can't be solved by byte swapping, but that's also true for signed integers (e.g. two's complement, one's complement, and sign-magnitude are all possible representations).  I focused my answer on how floating-point is different from integer.  The possibility that the `long double` type means a different precision on each endpoint of the communication, even when both endpoints are using IEEE floating-point exclusively, is an interesting one.